# Avoid duplicates in col values

Tags: sql

I have a sp result like,

```
 subject | Chapter no. |  marks
 English      1             99
 English      2             99
 English      3             99
 Science      1             100
 Science      2             100
```

This sp result is based on subject, each subject may have different `chapterno.` but the marks are based on the subject. So I have to avoid the duplication to avoid error while calculating the total marks.

Hence I need this like,

```
 subject | Chapter no. |  marks
 English      1             99
 English      2             0/null
 English      3             0/null
 Science      1             100
 Science      2             0/null
```

Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: where is the query ??? show some working

Comment: If you want to keep all that data not to remove it, just use group by. If you are using sql then read this. 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT MIN([Chapter no.]) AS col, subject
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY subject
```